# How to prove consistency of Natural Deduction systems

Tags: logic, proof-theory

In Dag Prawitz, *Natural Deduction A Proof-Theoretical Study* (1965), we have the system **I** of intuitionistic (first-order) logic based on eleven introduction- and elimination-rules : the 3 couples for the *connectives* $\lor$, $\land$ and $\rightarrow$, the two couples for the quantifiers and the $\bot_I$ rule [page 20].

The system **C** of classical logic is obtained with the addition of the $\bot_C$ rule.

The system **C’** is obtained from **C** excluding $\lor$ and $\exists$ and treating them as defined in the usual way [page 39].

It is assumed that the *negation* $\lnot A$ is an abbreviation for $A \rightarrow \bot$ [page 16] so that we do not need it.

A notion of *consistency* (if I’m not wrong) is not defined; Prawitz does not introduce a semantics, so that we can assume that a system is *inconsistent* if we have a *proof* [see page 24 for the definition] of $\bot$.

The first reference to *consistency* is on page 44 :

> **COROLLARY 3** [to the Theorem on normal deductions for classical logic] [the system] **C’** is consistent; in particular, $\bot$ is not provable in **C’**.

A similar result is not stated for **I**; may we say that it is “implicit” in the above result ?

Regarding both systems, it seems to me that we can prove their consistency simply “by inspection”, due to the fact that there are no rules that “introduce” $\bot$. Where is the flaw in this argument ?

**Added** following a comment by *Peter Smith*

In Prawitz's book [page 14] the symbol $\bot$ is a sentential constant (*absurdity*).

In absence of the *negation* symbol, we must apply Post's definition of *consistency*. So, proving that $\bot$ is underivable is equivalent to proving that not every proposition is derivable ?

***Added Jan,30***

I made a research into Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, *Structural Proof Theory* (2001), due to the similarity between Natural Deduction and sequent calculus.

They say [page 16] :

> The $\bot$E rule of natural deduction gives a zero-premiss sequent calculus rule: $$\frac{}{\bot \implies C}$$

Also, about **the subformula property** [pages 40-41] :

> Since structural rules can be dispensed with in **G3ip** [intuitionistic propositional calculus], we find *by inspection* [emphasis added] of its rules of inference that no formulas disappear from derivations [...]. Similarly, a connective that has once appeared in a derivation cannot disappear. From this it follows in particular that $\implies \bot$ is not derivable, i.e., the calculus is syntactically **consistent**.

So, my question becomes :

> May I exploit the similarity between the two calculus and conclude that, also for the system **I** of Prawitz, we can prove the consistency simply “by inspection”, due to the fact that there are no rules that “introduce” $\bot$ ?

Comment: almost see my remark to your earlier question, it depends on the logic and other more curious things, PS why a new question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the article of Andrés Raggio, DIRECT CONSISTENCY PROOF OF GENTZEN'S SYSTEM OF
NATURAL DEDUCTION (Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic, 1964).

The proof "by inspection" does not work in *Natural Deduction* : we have for example the $\lor$-elimination rule that allows us to "introduce" a new formula $C$ that is not a subformula of the major premisse $A \lor B$.

The same for $\lor$-introduction, where we pass from $A$ to $A \lor B$.

We need induction on the derivation-tree.

***Added March, 5***

Now I've got it !

See the detailed study of Gentzen's unpublished manuscript thesis of 1932 in Jan von Plato, *Gentzen's Proof Systems: byproducts in a work of genius* (The Bull of Sumb Log, 2012), page 329.

In Gentzen's thesis there is a *conjecture* about the normalization theorem for derivation in intuitionistic natural deduction, then transformed into a proof.

> In Gentzen's original presentation of *natural deduction*, finished formal derivations ended with the closing of all open assumptions. [...] With the closing of all open assumptions in the end, the conclusion became the longest formula in a derivation that also contained all the formulas in the derivation as subformulas, *if no detours had been taken* [emphasis mine].
>
> "A closer inspection of the natural deduction calculus led me in the end to a general theorem that I want to call the 'Hauptsatz'. [...] The natural calculus proved not to be suitable."

Then, Gentzen "moved to" *sequent calculus*, but von Plato in his paper shows that he was able to find a proof (unpublished) also for intuitionistic natural deduction.

In conclusion, the conjecture that, if we do not have $\bot$ in the axioms (assumptions) the system is *consistent*, is not in general true; in order to assert it, we must be able to "avoid detours". The result must be attained in *natural deduction* through the *normalization theorem*.

*Note.* In *natural deduction* the presence of $\supset$-E (*modus ponens*) plays the role of *cut* : from $A$ and $A \supset B$ we derive $B$; in this way, we lose the "trace" of $A$.

In a system based on *sequent calculus*, instead, the consistency proof "by inspection" works because the "no detours" condition is "built in" into the rules: no assumption is lost during the derivation.

So, if $\bot$ is not present into the axioms, we may conclude that it will not be present in the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

About the question :

> May we exploit the similarity between ND and *sequent calculus* in order to prove the consistency of **I** system simply “by inspection”, due to the fact that there are no rules that “introduce” $\bot$ ?

After having browsed Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, *Structural Proof Theory* (2001), Ch.8 : *Back to Natural Deduction*, I think that the "insight" is sound but it is not straightforward to transform into a proof, due to the nature of ND's rules , that admits assumptions.

They say [page 16] :

> The $\bot$E rule of natural deduction gives a zero-premiss sequent calculus rule: $$\frac{}{\bot \implies C}$$

Also, about **the subformula property** [pages 40-41] :

> Since structural rules can be dispensed with in **G3ip** [intuitionistic propositional calculus], we find *by inspection* [emphasis added] of its rules of inference that no formulas disappear from derivations [...]. Similarly, a connective that has once appeared in a derivation cannot disappear. From this it follows in particular that $\implies \bot$ is not derivable, i.e., the calculus is syntactically **consistent**.

We have that [page 183] :

> by the translation of a normal derivation in natural deduction to sequent calculus,
>   each formula in the former appears in the latter. We therefore have, by the subformula property of **G0i**, a somewhat surprising proof of
>
> **Corollary 8.3.3: Subformula property**. In a normal derivation of $C$ from open
>   assumptions $\Gamma$, each formula in the derivation is a subformula of $\Gamma$, $C$.

So (I think) is only after having obtained *normalization* that, from the *subformula property* we can conclude that a derivation of $\bot$ (i.e.*inconsistency*) is possible only if $\bot$ is a subformula of some of the premises.

If we apply this to the "pure" calculus, now we have *consistency* due to the fact that a proof of $\bot$ (i.e. $\vdash \bot$) would implies that $\bot$ is a subformula of the premises; but we have no premises.