# Help with a modal Hilbert-style proof of (□(a>b)&◊(a&c))>◊(b&c)

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Can't grasp how it can be proved. To proof just propositional calculus formula (without modal operators) at first seems rather natural to me. Tried the law of importation scheme but it didn't work out.

There are a lot of axiom schemata allowed (link below) + K + Necessitation + MP + Substituition

It does not really matter what Hilbert-style calculus to use. The only two requirements:

a) no assumptions

b) no premises

set of axioms is on a p.13
http://books.google.ru/books?id=XNzzliL2cBgC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=a+new+introduction+to+modal+logic+axioms&source=bl&ots=hOuN2jTOra&sig=dMGzFI6ZFf2RJa7GLLDNio9aM2E&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=-2y2U7n_KNOO4gSlmoGACA&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=a%20new%20introduction%20to%20modal%20logic%20axioms&f=true

Comment: It is not clear to me the statement : "any usage of valid sentences would work"; **if** we are considering the *propositional formula* : $((a \rightarrow b) \land (a \land c)) \rightarrow (b \land c)$, it is a *tautology*. Thus, by *Completeness* for *propositional calculus*, it is provable. If it can help, the formula is equivalent to : $(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow ((a \land c) \rightarrow (b \land c))$ which again is a *tautology*.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What the axioms for propositional calculus that you're using?  What the axioms for modal logic that you're using?  What rules can get used?

Comment: Mauro, yep it is not very clear. What I meant is that you may use any valid sentences (it will help me) excluding the given one.

Comment: Doug, there are abou 15 axioms allowed. As I have said it will be sufficient to use any valid sentences (excluding the presented one) since I need a hint. If your proof will include theorems apart from my allowed-axiom_schemata-and-theorems list I'll do necessary changes. My problem is that I cannot solve it even using any (!) theorems.

Comment: Mauro, you are right. p 13 [http://books.google.ru/books?id=XNzzliL2cBgC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=a+new+introduction+to+modal+logic+axioms&source=bl&ots=hOuN2jTOra&sig=dMGzFI6ZFf2RJa7GLLDNio9aM2E&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=-2y2U7n_KNOO4gSlmoGACA&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=a%20new%20introduction%20to%20modal%20logic%20axioms&f=false]

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I assume that your problem is Ex.2.1(c), page 48. The proof is relative to **system K**. At pages 24-25 the system is "specified" as : modal axiom K + Rule of Uniform Subst + Rule of Modus Ponens + Rule of Necessitation + the "propositional" axiom schema **PC** : is $\alpha$ is a valid wff of PC, then $\alpha$ is an axiom. The formula (see my comment above) : $((a→b)∧(a∧c))→(b∧c)$ is a *valid* wff of PC; thus, you can us "as is" in your proof.

Comment: @Mauro, yep, now I see. But now I've got kind of a sport interest to solve the problem(:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer address the "unsolved" problem regarding the proof of the "propositional part" of the question, using an *Hilbert-style* proof system (with *Natural Deduction*, the proof is quite easy, and has been already provided).

---

The list at page 13 of M.J.Cresswell & G.E.Hughes, [A New Introduction to Modal Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415126002) (1966) is significantly called a "list [of] valid PC wff"; we are not sure that they form a *complete* axiom system for PC (i.e. that they are enough to prove **all** tautologies).

In order to prove the formula :

> > $((a→b)∧(a∧c))→(b∧c)$

we need a complete *Hilbert-style* axiom system; I'll use that of Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412808307) (4th ed - 1997), based on the following three axioms :

> **(A1)**  $\mathcal{B} \rightarrow ( \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{B})$
>
> **(A2)**  $(\mathcal{B} \rightarrow ( \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D})) \rightarrow ((\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}) \rightarrow (\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}))$
>
> **(A3)**  $(\lnot \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow ((\lnot \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow \mathcal{C})$

and *modus ponens* as only rule of inference.

The symbol $\land$ for *conjunction* is not primitive; it is defined as :

> $\mathcal{B} \land \mathcal{C} =_{def} \lnot (\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal{C})$.

In order to prove our formula, we need some preliminary Lemmas; you can find the proof in Mendelson's book [for some of them, see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725016/give-a-proof-that-p-p-implies-q)].

**Lemma 1.8** [page 36] :

> $\vdash \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$.

We need only (A1) and (A2) to prove it.

With **Lemma 1.8** and using only (A1) and (A2) it is possible to prove the *Deduction Theorem* [**Prop 1.9**, page 37]:

> if $\Gamma, \mathcal{B} \vdash \mathcal{C}$, then $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$.

With the *Deduction Th* it is easy to prove :

**Corollary 1.10(a)** [page 38] :

> $\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}  \vdash \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$.

Then Mendelson proves **Lemma 1.11.(a)-(e)**

> $\vdash \lnot \lnot \mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal B$
>
> $\vdash \mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \lnot \mathcal B$
>
> $\vdash \lnot \mathcal B \rightarrow (\mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal C)$
>
> $\vdash (\lnot \mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal B) \rightarrow (\mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal C)$
>
> $\vdash (\mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal C) \rightarrow (\lnot \mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal B)$.

We can easily derive from **Lemma 1.11.(e)** :

> **Lemma A** : $\vdash (\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal C) \rightarrow (\mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal B)$.

*Proof*

*(i)* $\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal C \vdash \lnot \lnot \mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal B$ --- from Lemma 1.11.(e) with $\lnot \mathcal C$ in place of $\mathcal C$, by *mp*

*(ii)* $\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal C \vdash \mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal B$ --- from (i) and Lemma 1.11(b) with Coroll.1.10(a)

*(iii)* $\vdash (\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal C) \rightarrow (\mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal B)$ --- from (ii) by *DT*.

Now we need the equivalent of $\land$-introduction and -elimination rules; we have to derive them using the abbreviation for $\land$.

> **Lemma B** : $\vdash (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C) \rightarrow \mathcal B$.

*Proof*

*(i)* $\vdash \lnot \mathcal B \rightarrow (\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal C)$ --- Lemma 1:11(c)

*(ii)* $\vdash \lnot (\mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal \lnot C) \rightarrow \lnot \lnot \mathcal B $ --- from (i) and Lemma 1.11(e) by *mp*

*(iii)* $\vdash \lnot (\mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal \lnot C) \rightarrow \mathcal B $ --- from (ii) and Lemma 1.11(a) by Coroll.1.10(a)

*(iv)* $\vdash (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C) \rightarrow \mathcal B $ --- from (iii) by def of $\land$.

> **Lemma C** : $\vdash (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C) \rightarrow \mathcal C$.

*Proof*

*(i)* $\vdash \lnot \mathcal C \rightarrow (\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot C)$ --- (A1)

*(ii)* $\vdash \lnot (\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot C) \rightarrow \lnot \lnot C$ --- from (i) and Lemma 1.11(e) by *mp*

*(iii)* $\vdash \lnot (\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot C) \rightarrow C$ --- from (ii) and Lemma 1.11(a) by Coroll.1.10(a)

*iv)* $\vdash (\mathcal B \land C) \rightarrow C$ --- from (iii) by def of $\land$.

Now we prove :

> **Lemma D** : $\vdash \mathcal B \rightarrow ( \mathcal C \rightarrow (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C))$.

*Proof*

*(i)* $\mathcal B, \mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal C \vdash \mathcal \lnot C$ --- by *mp*

*(ii)* $\mathcal B \vdash (\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal C) \rightarrow \mathcal \lnot C$ --- from (i) by *DT*

*(iii)* $\mathcal B \vdash \mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot (\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal C)$ --- from (ii) and **Lemma A** by *mp*

*(iv)* $\vdash \mathcal B \rightarrow (\mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot (\mathcal B \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal C))$ --- from (iii) by *DT*

*(v)* $\vdash \mathcal B \rightarrow ( \mathcal C \rightarrow (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C))$ --- from (iv) def of $\land$.

We prove :

> **Lemma E** : $\mathcal B \rightarrow ( \mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal D) \vdash (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C) \rightarrow \mathcal D$.

*Proof*

*(i)* $\mathcal B \rightarrow ( \mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal D)$ --- assumed

*(ii)* $\mathcal B \land \mathcal C$ --- assumed

*(iii)* $\mathcal B$ --- from (ii) by **Lemma B**

*(iv)* $\mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal D$ --- from (i) and (iii) by *mp*

*(v)* $\mathcal C$ --- from (ii) by **Lemma C**

*(vi)* $\mathcal D$ --- from (iv) and (v) by *mp*

*(vii)* $\mathcal B \rightarrow ( \mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal D) \vdash (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C) \rightarrow \mathcal D$ --- from (i) and (vi) by *DT*.

Now our last preliminary Lemma:

> **Lemma F** : $\vdash (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C) \rightarrow (\mathcal C \land \mathcal B)$.

*Proof*

*(i)* $\mathcal B \land C$ --- assumed

*(ii)* $\mathcal B$ --- from (i) by **Lemma B**

*(iii)* $\mathcal C$ --- from (i) by **Lemma C**

*(iv)* $\vdash \mathcal C \rightarrow ( \mathcal B \rightarrow (\mathcal C \land \mathcal B))$ --- **Lemma D**

*(v)* $\mathcal C \land \mathcal B$ --- from (iii), (ii) and (iv) by *mp* twice

*(vi)* $\vdash (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C) \rightarrow (\mathcal C \land \mathcal B)$ --- from (i) and (v) by *DT*.

---

Now that we have in place all needed "tools", we can proceed with the proof of our theorem.

*Main proof*

*(i)* $\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B, \mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal \lnot C  \vdash \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal \lnot C$ --- from Coroll.1.10(a)

*(ii)* $\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B, \mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal \lnot B  \vdash \mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal A$ --- from (i) by Lemma A and Coroll.1.10(a) twice

*(iii)* $\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B \vdash (\mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal \lnot B)  \rightarrow (\mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal A)$ --- from (ii) by *DT*

*(iv)* $\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B \vdash \lnot (\mathcal C \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal A) \rightarrow \lnot (\mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal \lnot B)$ --- from (iii) and Lemma 1.11(e) by *mp*

*(v)* $\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B \vdash (\mathcal C \land \mathcal A) \rightarrow (\mathcal C \land \mathcal B)$ --- from (iv) by def of $\land$

*(vi)* $\vdash (\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B) \rightarrow ((\mathcal C \land \mathcal A) \rightarrow (\mathcal C \land \mathcal B))$ --- from (v) by *DT*

*(vii)* $\vdash (\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B) \rightarrow ((\mathcal A \land \mathcal C) \rightarrow (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C))$ --- from (vi) and **Lemma F** by Coroll 1.10(a) twice

> > *(viii)* $\vdash ((\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B) \land (\mathcal A \land \mathcal C)) \rightarrow (\mathcal B \land \mathcal C)$ --- from (vii) by **Lemma E**.

---

*Comment*

It is of interest to compare the above system with J.Barkley Rosser, [Logic for Mathematicians](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486468984) (1953 - Dover reprint).

The system has $\lnot$ and $\land$ as primitive and $\supset$ is defined through [see page 15] :

> $P \supset Q =_{def}\lnot (P \land \lnot Q)$.

The axioms are [see page 56 - using the abbreviation] :

> 1) $\quad P \supset (P \land P)$
>
> 2) $\quad (P \land Q) \supset P$
>
> 3) $\quad (P \supset Q) \supset (\lnot (Q \land R) \supset \lnot (R \land P) )$

while *modus ponens* is the only rule of inference.

In a manner similar to Mendelson's book, Rosser proves [pages 61-62] :

> **Theorem IV.4.1** : $P \supset Q, Q \supset R \vdash \lnot (\lnot R \land P)$
>
> **Theorem IV.4.2** : $\vdash \lnot (\lnot P \land P)$
>
> **Theorem IV.4.3** : $\vdash \lnot \lnot P \supset P$

Then he proves [page 63] :

> **Theorem IV.4.7** : $\lnot P \supset \lnot Q \vdash Q \supset P$.

Finally, we have :

> **Theorem IV.4.8** : $P \supset Q \vdash (R \land P ) \supset (Q \land R)$

*Proof*

*(i)* $P \supset Q \vdash \lnot (Q \land R) \supset \lnot (R \land P)$ --- axiom 3

*(ii)* $\lnot (Q \land R) \supset \lnot (R \land P) \vdash (R \land P) \supset (Q \land R)$ --- from **Th.IV.4.7** with $Q \land R$ for $P$ and $R \land P$ for $Q$

*(iii)* $P \supset Q \vdash (R \land P ) \supset (Q \land R)$ from (i) and (ii) by transitivity of $\vdash$.

To complete the proof of the formula in the OP's question, we need some more work :

- to prove the commutativity of $\land$ [see **Theorem IV.4.13**, page 64],
- to prove the *Deduction Theorem* [see **Theorem IV.6.1**, page 65].

Comment: Thank you, Mauro! You're the MVP!

Answer (score 2):

$\renewcommand{\lif}{\supset}$
First, it's important to understand the intuition behind the theorem.  That will help guide you in constructing an axiomatic proof.

$$
\renewcommand{\land}{\wedge}
(\Box (a \lif b) \land \Diamond(a \land c)) \lif \Diamond (b \land c)
$$

With the Kripke semantics, this says "if $a \lif b$ is true in *every* accessible world and $a \land c$ is true in *some* accessible world, then $b \land c$ must be true in *some* accessible world."  An intuition behind proof might be:

> Consider the accessible world $w$ in which $a \land c$ is true.  Because $a \lif b$ is true in every accessible world, it must be true in $w$ as well. Since $a$ is true (from $a \land c$), then $b$ follows by modus ponens.  Since $c$ is also true (from $a \land c$), then $b \land c$ is true.  Then $b\land c$ is true in some accessible world, and thus $\Diamond(b \land c)$.

Constructing axiomatic proofs from scratch is kind of a pain, and it might be easier to start with a natural deduction style proof, and then map that back to an axiomatic proof.  A natural deduction style proof would be something like

- 0.

  - 1. Assume $\Box(a \lif b) \land \Diamond(a \land c)$.
  - 2. $\Box(a \lif b)$ by conjunction elimination.
  - 3. $\Diamond(a \land c)$ by conjunction elimination.

    - 4. Possibility introduction subproof with $a \land c$.
    - 5. $a \lif b$ by K-reiteration.
    - 6. $a$ by conjunction elimination.
    - 7. $b$ by conditional elimination (modus ponens).
    - 8. $c$ by conjunction elimination.
    - 9. $b \land c$ by conjunction introduction.
  - 10. $\Diamond(b \land c)$ by $\Diamond$ introduction with 3, and 4–9.
- 11. $(\Box(a \lif b) \land \Diamond(a \land c)) \lif \Diamond(b\land c)$ by conditional introduction 1–10.

What can we do on the axiomatic side?  Well, if we take propositional reasoning for granted, we do, to begin:

- $\Box(a\lif b) \land \Diamond(a \land c)$ (hyp)
- $\Box(a \lif b)$ (taut. consequence)
- $(a \lif b) \lif ((a \land c) \lif (b \land c))$ (tautology)
- $\Box((a \lif b) \lif ((a \land c) \lif (b \land c)))$ (necessitation)
- $\Box(a \lif b) \lif \Box((a \land c) \lif (b \land c))$ (distribution)
- $\Box((a \land c) \lif (b \land c))$ (modus ponens)

At this point, you need to figure out what rules you've got available for handling possibility.  Ideally you'd have a possibility distribution axiom like

$$
\Box(\phi \lif \psi) \lif (\Diamond\phi \lif \Diamond\psi) \tag{Possibilitation}
$$

if you have that, or can derive it, then you can continue:

- $\Diamond(a \land c) \lif \Diamond(b \land c)$ (possibilitation)
- $\Diamond(a \land c)$ (taut. consequence)
- $\Diamond(b \land c)$ (modus ponens)

That's still not quite what you need, because you'd need a deduction theorem to get the conditional.  That means you'll need to go back a bit and figure out how to do all of this "one-layer removed".  This should be a good starting point, though.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I've updated my answer.  In $K$ you can't derive $\Diamond\phi$ from $\Box\phi$.  You need the axiom M (aka T) for that.  In Kripke semantics, $\Box\phi$ is true if $\phi$ is true in *every* accessible world, and $\Diamond\phi$ is true if $\phi$ is true in *some* accessible world.  $\Box\phi$ can be true when $\Diamond\phi$ if there are no accessible worlds.  Compare with $\forall$ and $\exists$: $\forall x.Rx \lif Px$ can be true even if $\exists x. Rx\land Px$ is false.  It just means that there aren't any $x$ such that $Rx$.

Comment: Thank you Joshua for this invaluable insight in the modal semantics. ND-style proof is very clear and straightforward, but I cannot elicit the Hilbert-proof without using hypotheses. All that I have at hand are axiom schemata and the substituition rule.

Comment: @CharlesBronson I very much hope that you also have the necessitation rule ($\vdash \phi / \vdash \Box\phi$), and modus ponens ($p \lif q, p / q$), or else I don't think you're going to be able to do this.  But as I did in my answer, we'll have to guess at what axioms are available unless you show them in the question.  Add them to the question please so that we can provide better, more applicable answers.

Comment: thank you for advice. Updated the question. The modal part itself is very easy, but I didn't expect such a failure on the propositional part):