# proving{$\neg(\forall x)\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$}$\models$$(\forall x)\alpha$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, formal-proofs

prove {$\neg(\forall x)\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$}$\vdash\space(\forall x)\alpha$

 Im not sure what is the convention, so to be clear I am talking about proving the formula from the seven axiom schemes:
$(A_1) \alpha \rightarrow(\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$
$(A_2) (\alpha \rightarrow(\beta \rightarrow \gamma))\rightarrow((\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)) $
$(A_3) (\neg\beta \rightarrow\neg\alpha)\rightarrow((\neg\beta \rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow\beta)$
$(A_4) (\forall x)\alpha\rightarrow \alpha(t)$ where $x\in FV(\alpha)$ and $\alpha(t)$ is the subtition of $t$ to all appearances of $x$ in  $\alpha$ 
 
$(A_5) (\forall x)(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow(\forall x)\beta))$ when $x\not\in FV(\alpha)$
$(A_6) (\forall x)x=x$
$(A_7) x=y\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\alpha<y>)$ where $y\in FV(\alpha)$ and $\alpha<y>$ is the subtition of $y$ to some appearances of $x$ in  $\alpha$
and the deduction rules (not sure about the accepted term but I hope you will understand) are:
 if $\alpha$ appeared in the proof then it is eligible to use $(\forall x)\alpha$
and 
if $\alpha\rightarrow\beta$ and $\alpha $appeared in the proof then it is eligible to use $\beta$

sorry if I misused some of the terms and if it's not a burden I'd like to be corrected.

Comment: Complete the list of axioms, please.

Comment: The set of axioms for *first-order* logic is not "so standard" as you presume... Thus, it would be better if you can list them all, or otherwise give us the reference to the math log textbook you are using. Thanks ...

Comment: please rewrite your formula with brackets to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to mathematical logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0412808307) (4ed - 1997), page 69.

We need at least a third *propositional axiom*, like :

> **(A3)** --- $(\lnot γ → \lnot β) → ((\lnot γ → β) → γ)$

to be able to prove all *tautologies*.

In addition, I assume two axioms for the predicate calculus (and two further axioms for *equality* : we do not need them here) :

> **(A4)** --- $\forall x \alpha(x) \rightarrow \alpha (t)$, where $t$ is a *term* free for $x$ in $\alpha(x)$
>
> **(A5)** --- $(∀x(\alpha → \beta) → (\alpha → ∀x \beta))$, where $x$ is not free in $\alpha$.

We need also *inference rules* :

> - *modus ponens*
> - *generalization* : form $\alpha$, $\forall x \alpha$ follows.

*Proof*

*(1)* $\lnot \forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha$ --- assumed

*(2)* $\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \alpha$ --- form (1) using the *tautology* : $(\lnot \varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\lnot \psi \rightarrow \varphi)$ and *modus ponens*

*(3)* $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha$ --- by axion (A4), with $x$ as $t$

*(4)* $\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \lnot \forall x \alpha$ --- from (3) as above

*(5)* $\alpha$ --- from axiom (A3) with (4) and (2), by *mp* twice

*(6)* $\forall x \alpha$ --- from (5) by *generalization*

Thus, form (1) and (6) :

> > $\lnot \forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \vdash \forall x \alpha$.

---

*Note*

In order to conclude from the above formula, by *soundness*, that :

> $\lnot \forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \vDash \forall x \alpha$

we have to check if the fine details regarding the definitions of *satisfaction* and *logical consequence* are consistent with those in Mendelson's book.

---

*Comment*

To prove the *tautology* : $(\lnot \varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\lnot \psi \rightarrow \varphi)$ we need some extra-work.

See this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855485/help-with-a-modal-hilbert-style-proof-of-%e2%96%a1ab%e2%97%8aac%e2%97%8abc) for the "basic tools" according to Mendelson's proof system :

> $\vdash \varphi \rightarrow \varphi$, *Deduction Theorem*, *Syllogism* and *Double Negation* laws.

With these theorems available, it is easy to prove the above tautology.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.