# What is the purpose of defining the negation of a proposition A as A $\rightarrow \bot$?

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics

I know that this definition is unrelated to the law of the excluded middle, but as a beginner in logic (I've studied the first half of Chiswell and Hodges' Mathematical Logic), the use of the name 'negation', and the fact that in truth tables the negation of a true proposition is false, and vice-versa, make me think of A $\rightarrow \bot$ as "A implies absurdity, therefore the opposite of A is true". But isn't that the law of the excluded middle, or at least a very similar idea?

Comment: How else would you _define_ negation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way of defining *negation* ($\lnot$), assuming *conditional* ($\rightarrow$).

When $A$ is *true*, $A \rightarrow \bot$ will be $TRUE \rightarrow FALSE$, which is *false*, and thus it works.

Of course, in order to define $\lnot$, we have to assume a new "primitive" concept : the *falsum* or *absurdity* ($\bot$).

Usually, in *natural deduction* $\bot$ is primitive; with it the basic rules for *minimal* and *intuitionistic* logic are stated.

In order to "extend" the set of rules to cover *classical* logic, we have to add a rule; it can be one of : *RAA*, *Exclude Middle*, *Double Negation* or *Dilemma* (see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot)).

*Added*

See Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447145577) (5th ed - 2013), page 29-on.

The connectives are usually "managed" by a couple or rules : *introduction* and *elimination*.

*Negation* is defined from $\bot$ and the rules for $\bot$ in *classical* logic are :

> > $$\frac {\bot} A \, (\bot \text {-E})$$

also called : *ex falso quodlibet*; and :

> > $$\frac {\frac {[\lnot A]} \bot } A \, \text{RAA}$$

Only with *(RAA)* we can derive *LEM*, i.e. $A \lor \lnot A$.

Comment: I've seen the post you linked, thanks. I get it that it works, that is, when A is true, $\lnot$A is false, and vice-versa. But then doesn't it mean that ($A \lor \lnot A$), the LEM, is always true?

Comment: Yes, but only in *classical* logic; in *intuitionistic* one, this is not true. It depend on the *rules* you use. (see my edit of the answer).