# How is the law of excluded middle necessary for proofs by contradiction?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

It is claimed that the law of excluded middle : $A \lor \neg A$, is a necessary principle for proving statements by contradiction (i.e. non constructively).

However, in first order logic, at least, proofs by contradiction may go as follows : If $\{T\ \cup \ \neg p\}\vdash p$, then by the deduction theorem,  $T \vdash (\neg p \rightarrow p) $, and then by the logical axiom $(\neg p \rightarrow p) \rightarrow p$ and modus ponens, $T \vdash ~p$.

So it seems $A \lor \neg A$ is never used in the above. In what sense is it then needed for non constructive proofs?

Comment: Which logical system you used for? I think you should provide the logical system which you use. (That is, you should provide the logical axioms and rule of inferences of which you use.)

Comment: $(\lnot p\to p)\to p$, which you claim is an axiom, is not intuitionistically valid.
(The similar-seeming statement $(p\to\lnot p)\to \lnot p$ *is* valid.)

Comment: (This does not address your question exactly, but I wrote [a short article](http://blog.plover.com/math/IL-contradiction.html) about misunderstandings of proof by contradiction in intuitionistic logic, which may be of some help.)

Comment: @tetori : I was thinking of Hilbert style deduction system for first order logic. The logical axioms are the boolean tautologies.

Comment: It's not necessary.  It's simply not necessary to have disjunction as a primitive connective of the system, and unless you have disjunction as a primitive connective of the logical system, you don't have law of the excluded middle.

Comment: If you're taking the boolean tautologies as axioms, then you've already included the law of the excluded middle in many equivalent forms, and you are not doing constructive logic.

Comment: @MJD : Ah I see. Can you then think of the LEM as a way of justifying/deriving (in the metalanaguage, I suppose), the boolean tautologies?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: MJD : I meant that the law of the excluded middle would, as a general principle, tell you that something can be either true or not true, and hence guide you to come up with the two valued classical logic. Once you've decided that, you can justifying saying that for example (¬p→p)→p is a tautology, because it is true under any truth assignment from your two valued set {T,F} to p. In intuitionist logic, where one rejects the law of excluded middle, a statement no longer may take from just two values, but rather from three {Provable, Leads to absurdity, or None of the above}

Comment: and so we can't define an analogue of a 'boolean tautology', as in classical logic.

Comment: Does T stand for True in your question?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the "logical axiom" $(\lnot p \to p) \to p$ actually applies [Peirce's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law) underneath (just subtituting $\bot$ in $Q$ and $p$ in $P$), and we can prove the equivalence of law of excluded middle and Perice's law (see [this page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_Law_is_Equivalent_to_Law_of_Excluded_Middle)). Therefore, you can say you don't need law of excluded middle to complete your proof, but you are introducing Perice's law now.

Hence, constructive logic (used by Coq) not just excludes law of excluded middle by default, but also Peirce's law and some other things that you may deem as axioms in classical logic. You can take a look at the last exercise of [this chapter in Logic Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Logic.html) and try to solve it out.

Comment: That's not an answer. It's a link to an answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think the author knew that it should be a comment, rather than a full-on answer, but lacked the >50 reputation required to comment. (Not that it's an excuse: they could and should expand it into a proper answer)

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer, and I actually did not know it should be a comment, because what follows from my original answer looks apparent to me.

Answer (score 1):

A proof by contradiction is not $\{T\ \cup \ \neg p\}\vdash p$. It is $\{T\ \cup \ \neg p\}\vdash \neg q$, where $q$ is a proposition such that $T \vdash q$.

For example, a proof by contradiction may terminates by $0=1$ or $0>1$ or anything else "obviously" (for the point of view of the theory $T$) false. This is why proof by contradiction is also called "proof ad absurdum".

So, in a proof by contradiction, you start with $\{T\ \cup \ \neg p\}\vdash p$ and somehow obtain $\{T\ \cup \ \neg p\}\vdash \neg q$ for some $q$ with $T \vdash q$. So, it means that $\{T\ \cup \ \neg p\}\vdash (\neg q \wedge q)$. This is now where the Law of Excluded Middle is invoked.

Comment: If {T ∪ ¬p}⊢(¬q∧q) then {T ∪ ¬p} ⊢p and you can just proceed as in my post.

Comment: @user114806: I don't get the "then" part in your comment.

Comment: Even in intuitionistic logic, $\lnot q\land q$ proves $p$.

Comment: MJD : How? In intuitionistic logic q^¬q means "there is a proof of q, and there is a proof that q leads to absurdity". How does that prove (an arbitrary) p?

Comment: @Taladris : If {T ∪ ¬p} proves (¬q∧q), then it is a boolean axiom that (¬q∧q)->p  (i.e. anything can be proven from a contradiction), and thus {T ∪ ¬p} also proves p.

Comment: @user114806 From $q$ deduce $q\lor p$.  From $\lnot q$ and $q\lor p$, deduce $p$.  Alternatively, $\lnot q$ is an abbreviation for $q\to\bot$, so from $q$ and $q\to bot$, deduce $\bot$, and from $\bot$, deduce $p$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that part of the problem is in the terminology used: thus, I'll prefer to avoid to speak of "proof by contradiction".

Consider the standard *natural deduction* rules for propositional logic ; see Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1447145577) (5th ed - 2013), page 30.

The rules for $\bot$ are :

> ($\bot$) $$\frac {\bot} \varphi$$

and :

> (*RAA*) $$\frac {\frac {[\lnot \varphi]} \bot } \varphi$$

See also page 157 for *intuitionistic logic* :

> We adopt all the rules of natural deduction for the connectives ∨,∧,→,⊥, ∃,∀ with the exception of the rule *RAA*.

The law of *Excluded Middle* and *RAA* are equivalent is classical logic; see also this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot) for some details.

A "standard" meta-theorem is [see page 41] :

> **Lemma**
>
> (a) if $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$,
>
> (b) if $\Gamma \cup \{ \varphi \}$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$.

The proof is done applying (*RAA*), for (a), and ($\rightarrow$-I), for (b).

---

*Added*

In an *Hilbert-style* proof system, usually *EM* ($\lnot A \lor A$) is not an axiom. We can see the proof system of Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0412808307) (4th ed - 1997), based on three axioms :

> **(A1)**  $\mathcal{B} \rightarrow ( \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{B})$
>
> **(A2)**  $(\mathcal{B} \rightarrow ( \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D})) \rightarrow ((\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}) \rightarrow (\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}))$
>
> **(A3)**  $(\lnot \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow ((\lnot \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow \mathcal{C})$

and *modus ponens* as only rule of inference.

We note that (A3) is *(RAA)* in "Hilbert-form".

Within this system we may prove *Ex Falso Quodlibet* [see Mendelsom, **Lemma 1.11(c)**, page 39] :

> $\lnot \mathcal B \rightarrow (\mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal C)$

(1) $\quad \lnot \mathcal B$ --- assumed

(2) $\quad \mathcal B$ --- assumed

(3) $\quad \vdash \mathcal B \rightarrow ( \lnot \mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal B )$ --- (A1)

(4) $\quad \vdash \mathcal{\lnot B} \rightarrow ( \mathcal{\lnot C} \rightarrow \mathcal{\lnot B})$ --- (A1)

(5) $\quad \mathcal{\lnot C} \rightarrow \mathcal B$ --- from (2) and (3) by *modus ponens*

(6) $\quad \mathcal{\lnot C} \rightarrow \mathcal{\lnot B}$ --- from (1) and (4) by *modus ponens*

(7) $\quad \vdash (\lnot \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow ((\lnot \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow \mathcal{C})$ --- (A3)

(8) $\quad \mathcal{C}$ --- from (5), (6) and (7) by *modus ponens* twice

(9) $\quad \lnot \mathcal B \rightarrow (\mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal C)$ --- from (1), (2) and (8) by *Deduction Th* twice.

As you can see, *(RAA)* is crucial in the above proof.

Using again (A3), it is easy to prove *Double Negation* [see **Lemma 1.11.a**, page 39] :

> $\vdash \lnot \lnot \mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal B$.

In Mendelson's system, $\lor$ is not primitive; it is defined through :

> $P \lor Q =_{def} \lnot P \rightarrow Q$.

Thus, **Lemma 1.11(a)** is simply *EM* :

> > $\vdash \lnot \mathcal B \lor \mathcal B$.