# Proof by Contradiction with Multiple Axioms

Tags: logic

Looking at proofs by contradiction and it seems I've run into something that does not sit well with me. I am fine with the law of the excluded middle (thus not an intuitionist) and more fundamentally the Principle of Explosion seems reasonable.

The standard form is:

$(P \wedge \neg Q \implies \bot) \implies (P \implies Q) $

However I've seen a number which claim to be reductio ad absurdem but follow the following format:

$(\neg P \implies \bot) \implies P $

Which seems to be not entirely robust when people use it in a similar way to as follows. Let:

$P = A \wedge B \wedge C$

Then through reductio ad absurdem they find that P is true. Thus any of A, B or C is true.

Think of the infinite primes proof with the original P statement, "If there are infinite primes and cats are plants". I'm concerned about this use. Thanks.

Comment: In *classical* logic : $((P \land \lnot Q) \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$ is simply : $\lnot (P \land \lnot Q) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$ which amount to : $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$. So, what are you meaning with : "standard form" ?

Comment: I was merely talking about the standard way in which I have seen these proofs being done. My logic and mathematics background is restricted to third year university mathematics and a Coursera logic course.

Comment: Your "second format" is a particular case of your "standard form". Note indeed that (i) $\neg Q$ is equivalent to $\top\land\neg Q$, and that (ii) $\top\Rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $Q$. Thus, your "standard form" $((P\land\neg Q)\Rightarrow \bot)\Rightarrow(P\Rightarrow Q)$ instantiates into $((\top\land\neg Q)\Rightarrow \bot)\Rightarrow(\top\Rightarrow Q)$, and this is turn equivalent, given (i) and (ii), to $(\neg Q\Rightarrow \bot)\Rightarrow Q$, a slight variation of your "second format".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *RAA* principle :

> $(¬P → \bot) → P$

can be equivalently rewritten as :

> $\lnot \lnot P → P$

which is *Double Negation*.

If you agree with it, you are using *classical* logic.

Thus, when you apply it to a "complex" statement like : $P := A \land B \land C$, you have simply :

> $\lnot \lnot (A \land B \land C) \rightarrow (A \land B \land C)$.

If we consider the original formulation : $(¬P → \bot) → P$, with $P := A \land B \land C$, the denial of $P$ amounts to :

> $\lnot (A \land B \land C)$

which, again in *classical* logic, is :

> $\lnot A \lor \lnot B \lor \lnot C$.

Proving that this assumption implies the *falsum* (i.e. $\bot$) amounts to saying that **no** one between $\lnot A,\lnot B,\lnot C$ is true, and thus that $A,B,C$ are all true.

Note : also the above use of disjunction is not intuitionistically allowed ...

---

In your example, you are trying to derive a contradiction (⊥) from the denial of :

Primes are infinite **and** Cats are plants

which is :

Primes are not infinite **or** Cats are not plants.

How can we do this ?

By the ∨-elim rule :

if P⊢A and Q⊢A, then P∨Q⊢A.

Assuming a "standard" theory of numbers, according to which we can prove that "Primes are infinite", we can derive ⊥ from the assumption : "Primes are not infinite" (the first disjunct).

But what about the second disjunct : "Cats are not plants" ?

Where is the contradiction ?

Comment: You are right. Thank you for spelling it out so clearly. I've had a number of lecturers do this very sloppily and effectively shown a contradiction and selected one of the many axioms used to be the one that is contradicted. Which is as you have pointed out sloppy logic. Fears allayed; logic stands as always.

Comment: @AER - I think that your "lecturers" mix-up different rules all naming them "proof by contradiction". It may help to see my answer to this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot). As you can see, the rule we are discussing is *RAA*, which is *classically* equivalent to *Excluded Middle* and *Double Negation*. We have another rule, which is *intuitionistically* valid, call the *Absurdity rule* or *Ex Falso Quodlibet* : "from $\bot$, derive $\varphi$". Is this rule which licences us, in presence of a contradiction ($\bot$) ... 1/2

Comment: ... to introduce a formula $\varphi$ whatever. There is also another rule, called $\lnot$-introduction : "if $\varphi \vdash \bot$, then $\lnot \varphi$". Of course, if you derive $\bot$ in a proof with more than one assumption, you can choose the assumption to be "blamed" for the contradiction , deriving its denial. 2/2

Answer (score 0):

The statement $P=$"there are infinite primes and cats are plants" cannot be proven by contradiction.

Since $\neg P$ is "There are finite primes or cats are not plants" is a true statement, the statement $\neg P\implies\bot$ is not true, so you cannot conclude that $P$ is true.

Comment: Do you mean "or cats are not plants"? What I'm saying is though you can use the first statement alone (by expanding the "and").

Comment: The negation of $A\wedge B$ is $\neg A \vee \neg B$, so yes.