# Proof, is $\lnot p \land \lnot q \vdash p \iff q$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I have derived the proof to some extent, mentioned below:-

$$\begin{array}{rll}
    1. &\lnot p \land \lnot q     &\text{Premise} \\
    2. &\lnot p                   &\land\text{elim},1 \\
    3. &\lnot q                   &\land\text{elim},1 \\
    4. &p                         &\lnot\text{elim},2 \\
    5. &q                         &\lnot\text{elim},3 \\
    6. &p \rightarrow q           &\rightarrow\text{intro},4,5     \\
    7. &q \rightarrow p           &\rightarrow\text{intro},4,5 \\
    8. &p \Leftrightarrow q       &\Leftrightarrow\text{intro},6,7
\end{array}$$

Is the above proof correct? Please correct me.

Comment: You'll want to enclose anything that's using mathjax  syntax in dollar signs

Comment: @Alan.. Thank you for the advice. I didn't know it before typing it. Will follow from next time.

Comment: **No** : step 4 amounts to derive $p$ from $\lnot p$, which of course is not allowed in a "sound" calculus.

Comment: @mauro.. then probably what is the correct proof. Could you explain me in steps. So that i can understand and correct my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof must be :

1) $\lnot p \land \lnot q$ --- premise

2) $\lnot p$ --- form 1) by $\land$-elim

3) $\lnot q$ --- form 1) by $\land$-elim

4) $p$ --- assumed [a]

5) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\lnot$-elim

6) $q$ --- from 3) and 5) by *RAA* (or *Double negation*)

7) $p \rightarrow q$ --- from 4) and 6) by $\rightarrow$-intro, discharging [a]

8) $q$ --- assumed [b]

9) $\bot$ --- from 3) and 8) by $\lnot$-elim

10) $p$ --- from 2) and 9) by *RAA* (or *Double negation*)

11) $q \rightarrow p$ --- from 8) and 10) by $\rightarrow$-intro, discharging [b]

> 12) $p \leftrightarrow q$ --- from 7) and 11) by $\leftrightarrow$-intro.

Comment: @Mauro..I don't get this point 5) ⊥ --- from 2) and 4) by →-elim. Is it -> or ~ elim? Please clarify.

Comment: @TheGaME - you can find in the answer to this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot) the various versions of the $\lnot$ rules.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not correct.

I'm assuming it's supposed to be some kind of natural deduction system, but the deductions you annotate with $\neg$elim and $\to$into don't follow any sane negation elimination or implication introduction rules I know.

For example you try to conclude $p$ from $\neg p$. That makes no logical sense "Socrates is mortal, ergo Socrates is not mortal"??

And your introduction of the $\to$s look like you think you have a rule saying "from $p$ and $q$ conclude $p\to q$". This rule is actually *sound*, but it is far too weak to be useful in general, and is almost certainly not the introduction rule your text has presented.

Comment: That's right. I just came to know about after refering few documents.