# Intuitionistic Logic: introduction and elimination rules for the universal and existential quantifiers

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, intuitionistic-logic

Are the natural deduction introduction and elimination rules for the universal and existential quantifiers in Intuitionistic Logic the same as those for Classical Logic?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are.

See [Intuitionistic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/).

In terms of "standard" *natural deduction* rules, the only rule rejected by Intuitionistic Lofic is *RAA* rule (or *Double Negation*, equivalent to *LEM* - see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot)).

Comment: Great. Thanks ever so much.