# Falsehood in a calculus of natural deduction

Tags: logic

How does the introduction rule and the elimination rule of falsehood ⊥ look like in a calculus of natural deduction?

Comment: "Introduction rule" or "induction rule"?

Comment: lol. I mean "introduction rule". What would be an induction rule of ⊥?

Comment: You can see also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid having any introduction rule for $\bot$ provided you define $\neg A$ to mean $A \to \bot$; then the '$\bot$-introduction rule' is really just $\to$-elimination, namely
$$\cfrac{A \quad \neg A}{\bot}$$

As for $\bot$-elimination, it's quite simply
$$\cfrac{\bot}{A}$$
That is, from a contradiction, you can deduce anything.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear, but it looks like you might want $\bot\rightarrow\phi$ for any (formula) $\phi$ and $\phi\wedge\neg\phi\rightarrow\bot$.