# Why do people say RAA(Reductio Ad Absurdum) is the same as $(\bot E)$?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

$(\bot E)$ is

> $\bot\vdash\psi$.

RAA(Reductio Ad Absurdum) says

> If $\{\Gamma,\neg\psi\}\vdash\bot$, then $\{\Gamma\}\vdash\psi$.

Yet, one of the solutions to my textbook exercises uses $(\bot E)$ and labels it (RAA) in its natural deduction proof as in the picture below. Is it a mistake?

[image]

**Update 1** : Is the picture below a correct usage of RAA in a natural deduction proof?

[image]

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I added an update to the question. Can you answer my update, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

- Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA30) (5th ed - 2013), page 30 and page 156.

Where the presentation consider both *intuitionistic* and *classical* logics, the distinction between:

> ($\bot$E): $\dfrac \bot \varphi$

and:

> (RAA): $\dfrac { [\lnot \varphi] \ldots \bot } \varphi$

has to be maintained.

---

You can see the answers to [what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot) for an overview of the different rules fo the *negation*.

Comment: I'm using the textbook written by "Chiswell & Hodges". Since the book doesn't explicitly introduce $(\bot E)$ and mention that (RAA) embeds $(\bot E)$, it was difficult to use (RAA) as the authors intended.

Answer (score 0):

About the update, in order to prove the sequent

$\{(\phi \lor \psi),(\neg \phi)\} \vdash \psi$

the following derivation is better:

$
(1)\dfrac{{(\phi \lor \psi)} \quad \quad {\dfrac{ 
\dfrac{{\not\phi^{(1)}} \quad \quad \quad \quad {\neg \phi}}{\quad \bot}(\neg E) 
}{\psi}(RAA)} \quad  \quad {\not\psi}^{(1)}}{\psi}(\lor E)
$