# Use Fitch system to proof ((p ⇒ q) ⇒ p) ⇒ p without any premise. ONLY FOR FITCH SYSTEM.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I know here has few similar questions, but I cannot figure out with those answer. Since for Fitch system, I can only use And Intro, And Elim, Or Inro, Or Elim, Neg Intro, Neg Elim, Impl Intro, Impl Elim, Biconditional Intro, and Biconditional Elim.

I know I need to assume (p=>q)=>p then for next I need to prove p, at the end I can use Imlo Intro. But I don't know how to prove p...

I saw some answers like:
(p=>q)=>p  assume 1
p          assume 2
~p         assume 3
q          neg Elim with 2 or 3

I stop at this step..NOt sure why I can get q from 2 and 3? Since Neg Elim follows this form ( ~~p get p) and also Neg Intro follows (p=>q, p=>~q, get ~p). But from what I learn I can not get the q from just assume 2 and 3...

I tried in Fitch system, But it doesn't work with the answer from other questions. So that's right I post here again. Wish someone can help me.

Comment: The "fine details" depend on the set of rules: unfortunately, there are some different systems called [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) and the differences are mainly located in the management of $\lnot$ (or of $\bot$, where $\lnot P$ is defined as $P \to \bot$ and thus the rules for $\lnot$ are derived from those for $\to$).

Comment: In the rules set I've linked, we have $\lnot$-Elim: "from $p, \lnot p$, derive $\bot$" that means: from a *contradiction* we can derive the propositional constant "the *falsum*" that is always *false*, and $\bot$-Elim: "from $\bot$, derive $q$", called *Ex Falso Quodlibet*. The two together licensed the derivation: "from $p, \lnot p$, derive $q$, with $q$ whatever", called the *Principle of Explosion*".

Comment: Another possibility os with *Double Negation Elimination*: "from $\lnot \lnot p$, derive $p$" as per answer below. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot) for a review of the rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

Maybe this works for your rules?

$\fitch{}{
\fitch{
1. (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow p \quad Assumption}{
\fitch{
2. \neg p \quad Assumption}{
\fitch{
3. p \quad Assumption}{
\fitch{
4. \neg q \quad Assumption}{
5. p \quad Reiteration \ 3}\\
6. \neg q \rightarrow p \quad \rightarrow  Intro \ 4-5\\
\fitch{
7. \neg q \quad Assumption}{
8. \neg p \quad Reiteration \ 2}\\
9. \neg q \rightarrow \neg p \quad \rightarrow Intro \ 7-8\\
10. \neg \neg q \quad \neg  Intro \ 6,9\\
11.   q \quad \neg Elim \ 10}\\
12. \quad \quad p \rightarrow q \quad \rightarrow Intro \ 3-11\\
13. \quad \quad p \quad \rightarrow  Elim \ 1,12}\\
14. \quad \neg p \rightarrow p \quad \rightarrow  Intro \ 2-13\\
\fitch{
15. \quad \quad \neg p \quad Assumption}{
16. \quad \quad \neg p \quad Reiteration \ 15}\\
17. \quad \neg p \rightarrow \neg p \quad \rightarrow  Intro \ 15-16\\
18. \quad \neg \neg p \quad \neg Intro \ 14,17\\
19. \quad p \quad \neg Elim \ 18}\\
20. ((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow p) \rightarrow p \quad \rightarrow Intro \ 1-19
}$

Comment: Oh my god~! You are amazing~!!! It bothers me from last night. I am so shame of myself. ;(

Comment: @tangaqua Do not be ashamed!  These logic proofs can be quite tricky!

Answer (score 2):

The issue with this problem seemed to be [Stanford Fitch's](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php) approach to the negation rules, and their lack of a falsum symbol.

---

To prove the conditional $(p\to(p\to q))\to p$, assume $(p\to q)\to p$ aiming to derive $p$.  IE a conditional proof.

To derive $p$ from that assumption, assume $\lnot p$ aiming to derive a contradiction. Ie a proof by contradiction.

To derive a contradiction from $\lnot p$ and $(p\to q)\to p$, seek to derive $p\to q$.

To derive $p\to q$ from those assumptions, use a conditional proof. Ie: now assume $p$.

To derive $q$ from the assumptions of $p$, $\lnot p$, and $(p\to q)\to p$, well, we have assumed a contradiction so explode it.

Discharge the assumptions and we are done.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{~~1.~(p\to q)\to p\hspace{5ex}\text{Assume}}{\fitch{~~2.~\lnot p\hspace{11ex}\text{Assume}}{\fitch {~3.~p\hspace{10ex}\text{Assume}}{~~4.~\bot\hspace{8ex}\lnot\,\mathsf E, 2,3\\~~5.~q\hspace{9ex}\text{EFQ}}\\~~6.~p\to q\hspace{7ex}\to\mathsf I,3{-}5\\~~7.~p\hspace{12ex}\to\mathsf E, 1,6\\~~8.~\bot\hspace{12ex}\lnot\,\mathsf E,2,7}\\~~9.~\lnot\lnot p\hspace{13ex}\lnot\,\mathsf I,2{-}8\\10.~p\hspace{16ex}\lnot\lnot\,\mathsf E, 9}\\11.~(p\to (q\to p))\to p\hspace{2ex}\to\mathsf I,1{-}10}$$

Now, the Stanford Fitch implimentation's of the negation introduction rule isn't too cumbersome (and what they call negation elimination is usually known as double negation elimination), but the lack of a falsum symbol means they do not have an explicit *ex falso quodlibet* rule (EFQ).  You have to use a proof by contradiction using their negation rules.   It bloats the proofs somewhat.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{~~1.~(p\to q)\to p\hspace{5ex}\text{Assume}}{\fitch{~~2.~\lnot p\hspace{11ex}\text{Assume}}{\fitch {~3.~p\hspace{10ex}\text{Assume}}{\color{red}{\fitch{~~4.\lnot q\hspace{5ex}\text{Assume}}{~~5.~\lnot p\hspace{5ex}\mathsf R, 2}\\~~6.~\lnot q\to\lnot p\hspace{2ex}\to\mathsf I, 4{-}5\\\fitch{~~7.~\lnot q\hspace{5ex}\text{Assume}}{~~8.~p\hspace{7ex}\mathsf R, 3}\\~~9.~\lnot q\to p\hspace{3ex}\to\mathsf I, 7{-}8\\10.~~\lnot\lnot q\hspace{6ex}\lnot\,\mathsf I,6,9}\\11.~q\hspace{9ex}\lnot\lnot\,\mathsf E,10}\\12.~p\to q\hspace{7ex}\to\mathsf I,3{-}11\\13.~p\hspace{12ex}\to\mathsf E, 1,12}\\14.~\lnot p\to p\hspace{9ex}\to\mathsf E, 2{-}13\\\fitch{15.~\neg p\hspace{12ex}\text{Assume}}{}\\16.~\lnot p\to\lnot p\hspace{7.5ex}\to\mathsf I,15{-}15\\17.~\lnot\lnot p\hspace{13ex}\lnot\,\mathsf I,14,16\\18.~p\hspace{16ex}\lnot\lnot\,\mathsf E, 17}\\19.~(p\to (q\to p))\to p\hspace{2ex}\to\mathsf I,1{-}18}$$

Answer (score 0):

## proof

```
GOAL:     ((p => q) => p) => p                     conclusion
```

When trying to prove a conditional:

> 1. Assume the antecedent
> 2. Try and derive the consequent from your assumption.

In our case `(p => q) => p` is the antecendent.
`p` is the consequent.

So now we created a separate sub-problem which we have to solve in order to solve our main problem.

---

## Sub-proof

```
1. (p => q) => p             premise

...

GOAL:   p                     conclusion
```

How do we prove an atom `p` when given a conditional?
Well we have to use *reductio ad absurdum*.
We assume the negation of our atom `~p`. And we attempt to derive a contradiction.

So now we have created a sub-sub-problem.

---

## Sub-sub-proof

```
1. ~p             premise

...

GOAL:   ~p => z
        ~p => ~z                    conclusion
```

where `z` is some expression.

## Instantiating our sub-sub-proof

```
0. (p => q) => p          premise (we are allowed to reuse this information from the main proof in this subproof)

1. ~p                     premise
2.     p                  assumption 
3.         ~q             assumption
4.         p              reiteration                 2
5.     ~q => p            implication introduction    4-5
6.         ~q             assumption
7.         ~p             reiteration                 1
8.     ~q => ~p           implication introduction    6-7
9.     ~~q                negation introduction       5,8
10.    q                  negation elimination        9
11. p => q                implication introduction    1-11
12. p                     implication elimination     0,11
~p => p
```

Combining the conclusion of our sub-sub-proof with the tautology `~p => ~p` we get our desired contradiction.

## All together

```
1.     (p => q) => p             assumption
2.         ~p                    assumption 
3.             p                 assumption
4.                 ~q            assumption 
5                  p             reiteration                 2
6.             ~q => p           implication introduction    4-5
7.                 ~q            assumption
8.                 ~p            reiteration                 2
9.             ~q => ~p          implication introduction    7-8
10.            ~~q               negation introduction       6,9
11.            q                 negation elimination        10
12.        p => q                implication introduction    3-11
13.        p                     implication elimination     1,12
14.    ~p => p                   implication introduction    2,13   
15.        ~p                    assumption
16.    ~p => ~p                  implication introduction    15,15
17.    ~~p                       negation introduction       14,16
18.    p                         negation elimination        17
  ((p => q) => p) => p           implication introduction    1,18
```