# Are the following logical statements all axioms of propositional calculus?

Tags: propositional-calculus, axioms

I have found conflicting lists of axioms in propositional calculus in Kleene, $2002$, and on Wikipedia. From what I can tell, carefully reasoning through each of the statements reveals that are tautologies, and since the only real understanding I have surroundings logical axioms is that they are tautologies, I can't quite decide which source to trust.

> Wikipedia's axioms:[image]
>
> Kleene's axioms:
> [image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different (but equivalent) axiomatizations of propositional calculus. See e.g. [List of Hilbert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems).

The fist nine are the same.

Kleene's version does not use the $\Leftrightarrow$ connectives; thus, the last three axioms of Wiki's list are not needed in Kleene's version.

The only real difference regards the axioms fo $\lnot$.

Kleene's axiom 10 is Double Negation elimination : it is equivalent to LEM (axiom not-3).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I had a skim over the cited list; interesting stuff.

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt - regarding $\lnot$ and different equivalent sets of rules (or axioms) you can see the answer to [this  post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot).

Comment: The way this gets phrased suggested that the above consist of axioms.  None of what gets listed though makes for an axiom since none of those are well-formed, and by definition, an axiom has to be well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

No, what gets listed are not axioms.  None of those are well-formed, and thus to call them axioms is not correct.  That said, it probably isn't difficult for many who know an appropriate definition of a well-formed formula to write the intended axioms from the symbols given.

Comment: The assumption in both cases is that the symbols that are used to stand in for statements are well-formed.

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt If some sequences of symbols A gets used to stand in for a well-formed statement, then A is not well-formed.  If B is an axiom, then it it is well-formed.  So, A cannot be an axiom without a contradiction.

Comment: How does this assumption "Let $\phi$, $\mathcal{X}$, and $\psi$ stand for well-formed formulas. (The well-formed formulas themselves would not contain any Greek letters, but only capital Roman letters, connective operators, and parentheses.) Then the axioms are as follows" aid the composition of axioms, in which case?

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are many equivalent axiomatizations of propositional logic; the one that gets used is up to you. It is possible to prove that a theory is complete by showing that any tautology in the the theory is provable. For all of these axiom systems, their completeness has been proven. Some axiom systems prefer to be incomplete, such as theories which do not accept the law of excluded middle. Different axiom systems have different strengths and weaknesses, depending on what you're trying to prove.