# Why are constants considered $0$-arity functions in logic?

Tags: logic

I always come across this idea. It seems that constants can be considered nullary/$0$-arity functions. What is the intuition behind that?

Comment: See the discussion is the post [What is the “correct” reading of ⊥?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot)

Comment: And yes; in first-order logic an individual *constant* $c$ can be seen as a $0$-ary *function* symbol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function of arity $n$ on the universe $A$ is a function
$$
f \colon A^n \to A.
$$

Of course $A^0$ has only one point, say $*$.  So a function
$$
f \colon A^0 \to A
$$
is the constant function with value $f(*)$.

Answer (score 6):

It makes sense if we consider an object to be a function of the least possible arity. Just as $x^3$ depends only on $x$ but not on $y$ so can be defined to have an arity of $1$ instead of $2$, a constant has arity $0$ (if we say so). You can think of it in programming terms (I'll use Python):

```
def arity_1_function(x): return x ** 3
def arity_0_function(): return 12
```

In general a function can have greater arity than this approach assumes, so we could think of a constant as having any non-negative arity; all we're doing here is identifying a constant with a minimum-arity function as a convention.