# Is it possible to prove that propositional calculus is consistent using only its syntax?

Tags: propositional-calculus, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

Let us consider Gentzen's propositional calculus with only one axiom:
$$
\phi \vdash \phi
$$

and 12 rules of inference.

As far as I know this PC is *consistent*, i.e. not all of their expressions (sequents) are provable. In the book I read (russian edition only, I suppose) there is a proof of this fact. But it uses an interpretation of PC:
$$
f_X : \phi \to x,\qquad x\in \mathcal{P}(X),
$$
where $X$ is some set. For example,
$$
f_X(\neg\phi) = X\setminus f_X(\phi)
$$
Then it is proven that the sequent $\phi\wedge\neg\phi$ is not provable:
$$
f_X(\vdash\phi\wedge\neg\phi) = f_X(\phi) \cap X\setminus f_X(\phi) = \emptyset = X
$$
which is false since $X$ is not empty.

I have a question here. In the above proof we used ''additional structure'' $f_X$ which is not part of calculus - its semantics.
**Question**: how to prove the consistency of PC using only its syntax?

Comment: See the related post [how-to-prove-consistency-of-natural-deduction-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655776/how-to-prove-consistency-of-natural-deduction-systems).

Comment: We can use the relationship with sequent calculus and the [Subformula property](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subformula+property).